# facebook SDK for PHP v5.0 - Facebook\FacebookSession not found

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'm trying use the `Facebook\FacebookSession` file but it doesn't exist in the `sdk` folder that just downloaded from this [link:](https://github.com/facebook/php-graph-sdk)  it's the v5.4
here's a capture of the `src/Facebook` folder

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvmrN.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zn1kE.png)

Comment: FacebookSession was removed since v4. See [the docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/FacebookSession/5.0.0)

Comment: thanks for the information, and how can i send get requests without declaring a session variable ??

Comment: i'm trying to do somthing like this : $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'GET',
      '/' . $leadgen_id
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $lead = $response->getGraphObjectList();

Comment: PS : i found this code in facebook documentation

Comment: Where did you find this? Everything under https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/gettingstarted should be up-to-date, and the examples in that section should all work with the v5 SDK. (If you find places where that is not the case, you can file a documentation bug and ask them to please update it. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/)

Comment: i'll do that, here the example link : https://developers.facebook.com/ads/blog/post/2014/12/11/real-time-updates-for-page-conversions/?__mref=message_bubble